Get a kernel module's name by an address in Linux
I need to automatically identify a failing module by its name within the kernel space on an x86 architecture. The challenge is that I only have a random memory address associated with the failing module at the time of failure. I'm looking for a method to determine the module's name based solely on this address. I envisioned something like the pseudocode below, but haven't been able to find a way to fully implement this approach:
void get_mod_name(unsigned long addr)
{
    struct module *mod;
    foreach(&mod, all_modules) {
        if(in_mod_addr_range(mod, addr))
            printk(KERN_WARNING "Module's name is: %s", mod->name);
    }
}

Any thoughts? I've already considered that there's a m̀odules list in context of kernel/module/internal.h, but still can't figure it out how to access it and provide the information I need.

You can't, that variable is not exported. If you want to modify the kernel itself and compile your own version then you can export it, otherwise there isn't much to do except silly hacks to find and iterate the module list manually.

Failing how? The necessary information is provided by all variants of Oops traces in the kernel log.

You can get the start of each module by reading, as root, /proc/modules
rfcomm 102400 16 - Live 0xffffffffc1e70000
snd_seq_dummy 12288 0 - Live 0xffffffffc1e6a000
snd_hrtimer 12288 1 - Live 0xffffffffc1e60000
xt_CHECKSUM 12288 1 - Live 0xffffffffc1e5a000
xt_MASQUERADE 16384 3 - Live 0xffffffffc1e52000
xt_conntrack 12288 1 - Live 0xffffffffc1e4c000

Since these are in order from highest to lowest, you can stop when you find an address lower than your target.

Specifically look at what's done in https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.11.4/source/kernel/module/procfs.c

@o11c: The file kernel/module/procfs.c uses variable modules for iterate over the loaded modules. Given variable is not accessible for a kernel module's code.

That's by design.  Programs belong in userspace.  The kernel only provides services and manages resources.
